# No procedure with the name `gds.beta.node2vec.stream`

Tags: neo4j, graph-data-science

I am trying to use node2vec in Neo4j Desktop. My DB is v. 4.4.4. I have installed Graph Data Science Library (1.8.5) from the plugins tab. But when I try to use "CALL gds.beta.node2vec.stream" I get

> There is no procedure with the name `gds.beta.node2vec.stream`
> registered for this database instance. Please ensure you've spelled
> the procedure name correctly and that the procedure is properly
> deployed.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure that you have restarted the instance after the GDS installation. (Of course) this happened to me also and I was 100% sure that I have restarted ;) Tried it at my machine with 4.4.4 and 1.8.5 and it worked.

Comment: It seems that when I upgraded neo4j db to 4.4.4, Graph Data Science plug-in was disabled. Thank you @meistermeier for your comment it helped me notice this.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that you add below configs in $NEO4J_HOME/conf/neo4j.conf where $NEO4J_HOME is your home directory where neo4j server is installed.

```
    dbms.security.procedures.unrestricted=gds.*
    dbms.security.procedures.allowlist=gds.*
```

Then RESTART the neo4j server using below:

```
    $NEO4J_HOME/bin/neo4j restart
```